# How do I serialize Saxon's DocumentInfo to a String?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, saxon

If using the vanilla XML DOM, I can serialize a `Document` object to a `String` in Java like this:

```
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
    String result = stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
```

If I'm using the S9 API that's part of [Saxon 9.7 HE](http://www.saxonica.com/products/PD9.7/HE.pdf), and I have `DocumentInfo` object, how can I serialize it to a `String`?

---

**Edit**: Here's a complete working example, which is based upon @Michael Kay's answer:

```
    Processor processor = new Processor(false); // False = does not required a feature from a licensed version of Saxon.
    Serializer serializer = processor.newSerializer();
    // Other properties found here: http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Serializer.Property.html
    serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
    XdmNode xdmNode = new XdmNode(documentInfo);
    String result = serializer.serializeNodeToString(xdmNode);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, firstly, the DocumentInfo isn't actually part of the s9api API: in s9api, a node is represented by an XdmNode object.

One way you can serialize a DocumentInfo is using exactly the code you have shown us: NodeInfo extends Source, so you can use it as the first argument of transform().

But in s9api the simplest approach is:

```
Processor proc = new Processor();
Serializer ser = proc.newSerializer();
ser.setOutputProperty(....);
ser.serializeNode(node);
```

In that code, "node" is an XdmNode; if you want to use a DocumentInfo, then you can call the constructor

```
new XdmNode(documentInfo);
```